# Issues with changing images for players in Pygame using classes

Tags: python, image, class, pygame

I have run into issues with my generic `Player` class for my character in a simple RPG game I am developing.

I am trying to make it so that when I press the 'left' key to move left the character not only goes left but also changes its image to look like it is running left by my current code (attached below) keeps crashing with various errors.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image_normal = pygame.image.load('images/player/normal.png').convert()
    image_left = pygame.image.load('images/player/left.png').convert()
    image_right = pygame.image.load('images/player/right.png').convert()

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT):
        """Move the player."""
        if UP == True:
            if self.rect.y > 0:
                self.rect.y -= 5
        if DOWN == True:
            if self.rect.bottom < WIN_HEIGHT:
                self.rect.y += 5
        if LEFT == True:
            self.image = image_left
            if self.rect.x > 0:
                self.rect.x -= 5
        if RIGHT == True:
            self.image = image_right
            if self.rect.right < WIN_WIDTH:
                self.rect.x += 5
        else:
            self.image = image_normal
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\StoD\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import player
  File "D:\StoD\player.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  File "D:\StoD\player.py", line 16, in Player
    image_normal = pygame.image.load('images/player/normal.png').convert() 
pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized
```

Comment: Please post the Error Messages including the complete Stack Trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\StoD\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import player
  File "D:\StoD\player.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #create the player class as an instance of a Pygame sprite
  File "D:\StoD\player.py", line 16, in Player
    image_normal = pygame.image.load('images/player/normal.png').convert()
pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized

Comment: Can you update your question with the error message you've provided in the comment?

Comment: @greg please refrain from editing noice like hi / hola / yo / hello / whatever into posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not use pygame.image.load for a class attribute? It says "cannot convert without pygame.display initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319550/why-can-i-not-use-pygame-image-load-for-a-class-attribute-it-says-cannot-conve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have not initialised `pygame.display` as this Error tells you

```
pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized
```

I would load the images in the Player Class like this:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #create the player class as an instance of a Pygame sprite
   image_normal = []
   image_left = []
   image_right = []

   def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #init the Pygame sprite
        #load all images
        self.image_normal = pygame.image.load('images/player/normal.png').convert()
        self.image_left = pygame.image.load('images/player/left.png').convert()
        self.image_right = pygame.image.load('images/player/right.png').convert()
        self.image = self.image_normal    #load the player image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()   #get a rect for the player
```

and if you need a different image do one of these:

```
self.image = self.image_left
self.image = self.image_right
self.image = self.image_normal
```

Comment: It now says that global variable 'image_normal' has not been defined... but defining outside of __init__ means nothing works... [EDIT] This error is actually coming from the update function that changes the image and moves the character so where should I load the images now?

Comment: I initialised the display in main.py with pygame.init() and then called player = Player() to create my player.

Comment: Another Thought: Sprite is maybe not what you want to use after all.. Sprites are normally used for objects that you create more than once (like bullets). You may want to create ja player object that does not inherit from sprite but has a draw method that blits the image you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and all your help. After experiencing issues the player revert to the 'normal' state when no key was being pressed I realized I could just call self.image = self.image_normal as the first line of the update() function to reset the image and then change it back to image_left or image_right if required. Thanks for the help again.