# Why can I not use pygame.image.load for a class attribute? It says "cannot convert without pygame.display initialized"

Tags: python, pygame

The following block produces the error `cannot convert without pygame.display initialized` when used as a class attribute:

```
class Tile:
    hidden_image = pygame.image.load('image0.bmp')
    hidden_image.convert()
```

However, when I use it under any method of class `Tile`, it works. i.e.

```
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image):
        .....

    def draw(self):
        hidden_image = pygame.image.load('image0.bmp')
        hidden_image.convert()
```

Any explanation?

Comment: always show full error message.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run `pygame.init()` or rather `pygame.screen.set_mode()` before you run `hidden_image.convert()` because `convert()` has to know display configuration - ie. color depth - to correctly convert image.

Because it is class attribute so it is executed at start when script is loaded so you have to put `pygame.init()` and `pygame.screen.set_mode()` before class definition. Or you have to use `convert()` in `__init__`.

`draw()` function is executed after `pygame.screen.set_mode()` so it works.

PyGame doc: [pygame.Surface.convert](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert)