# Pygame in python

Tags: python, pygame

My game was working before I added lines 7 and 8.
what happened in the game was the red sprites that fall down the screen would hit the main character sprite which is green and the game would stop just as I need it to.

```
import pygame
import random

from os import path
img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__),'PNG')

background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,'Space-Background.png')).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH/2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT-10
        
        self.speedx = 0
        
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
            
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centrex,self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)
            
class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30,40))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100,-40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1,8)
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT +10:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100,-40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1,8)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,20))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centrex = x
        self.speedy = -10
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

# player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"spaceShips_003.png")).convert()
# bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"spaceMissile_006.png")).convert()
# mob_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"SpaceMeteor_004.png")).convert()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)
    
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()
    all_sprites.update()
    
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs,bullets,True,True)
    for hit in hits:
         m = Mob()
         all_sprites.add(m)

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,mobs,False)
    
    if hits:
        running = False
        
    screen.fill(BLACK)
#    screen.split(background.background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
        
            
pygame.quit()
```

After I added the two lines for the images there was an error message. I am not sure what happened and I need some help fixing it.

```
>>> %Run trial.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.7.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mish Mash\Documents\School File\trial.py", line 7, in <module>
    background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,'Space-Background.png')).convert()
pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the error message didn't prompt you to move these two lines below `pygame.init()` and see if that helps. Or maybe below `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class attributes failed to access pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319550/class-attributes-failed-to-access-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the following error: `pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized` is that you are trying to use a method of `pygame.display` **(the `convert` method)** without initializing `pygame` first. To fix this, simply move `pygame.init()` to below the import statements.

## Code

```
import pygame
import random

from os import path

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'PNG')

background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'Space-Background.png')).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10

        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5

        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centrex, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)


class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 20))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centrex = x
        self.speedy = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()


# player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"spaceShips_003.png")).convert()
# bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"spaceMissile_006.png")).convert()
# mob_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir,"SpaceMeteor_004.png")).convert()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)

all_sprites.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()
    all_sprites.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)

    if hits:
        running = False

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    #    screen.split(background.background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```